# Enabling 2nd level cache in Spring JPA

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Since managing sessions, transaction and other stuff is not required in Spring Data JPA unlike Hibernate, is there any way 2nd level caching can be enabled in Spring Data JPA? I tried google but it all takes me to articles of Hibernate (I understand that Hibernate works as a default spring JPA implementation but I don't understand if caching can be handled explicitly as it is done in Hibernate).

I am new to this topic.

Comment: Spring Data JPA is nothing but a wrapper on top of JPA for which Hibernate is the default implementation. So you need to configure the right hibernate properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference. So enable like Hibernate:
Put the below in the application.properties:

```
# Enable second-level cache
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache=true

# Specify the caching provider (Ehcache, Hazelcast, etc.)
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.region.factory_class=org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory
```

and below is your entity:

```
@Entity
@Cacheable
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class YourEntity {
    // Entity definition
}
```